# Jquery didn't identify the min max float number

Tags: jquery, html

I am Working on Two Select Box In which User Simply select `Min` & `Max` Value from Dropdown.

**I am Simply Preventing a User to select `Max` Value which is less than `Min` Value.**

I am Using Jquery to Prevent the user to select the "Max Value Which is Less then Min Value"

> Case 1: Example If the user selects `4.6` from `Min` Select Box and If
>   select option less then `4.6` then it gives an error message.  But
>   Problem is that if User Select options `10`, `11`, `12+` then it gives
>   an error.

```js
$('body').on('change', '#exp_max', function() {

  var min_exp = $('#exp_min').val();
  var max_exp = $(this).val();
  if (max_exp < min_exp) {
    console.log('Max Experience Cannot be Less then Min Experience');
    // $.Notification.autoHideNotify('error', 'top right', 'Max Experience Cannot be Less then Min Experience.','Experience');
    $(this).prop('selectedIndex', 0);
  }
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="col-lg-5">
  <select class="form-control" required data-parsley-minlength="1" id="exp_min" name="exp_min">
    <option value="">Min</option>
    <option value="-1">Last Year Student</option>
    <option value="0">Fresher</option>
    <option value="0.6" >0.6</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="1.6" >1.6</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="2.6">2.6</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="3.6">3.6</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="4.6">4.6</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12+</option>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-5">
  <select class="form-control" data-parsley-type="number" id="exp_max" name="exp_max">
    <option value="">Max</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="1.6">1.6</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="2.6">2.6</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="3.6">3.6</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="4.6">4.6</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12+</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: you probably want to do a `parseFloat` on your vals: `parseFloat($('#exp_min').val())`

Comment: Why to do so long operations, showing message to user as an error message, when you can simply ignore those options in the max select list where the value is less than the selected min option. Check my answer.

Comment: I have also tackled the issue where you select the max value first and then the min value. You can work around with the code and analyze it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `parseFloat`, below is the updated code:

```js
$('body').on('change', '#exp_max', function() {

  var min_exp = $('#exp_min').val();
  var max_exp = $(this).val();
  if (parseFloat(max_exp) < parseFloat(min_exp)) {
   console.log('Max Experience Cannot be Less then Min Experience');
    //$.Notification.autoHideNotify('error', 'top right', 'Max Experience Cannot be Less then Min Experience.', 'Experience');
    $(this).prop('selectedIndex', 0);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-lg-5">
  <select class="form-control" required data-parsley-minlength="1" id="exp_min" name="exp_min">
   <option value="">Min</option>
   <option value="-1">Last Year Student</option>
   <option value="0">Fresher</option>
   <option value="0.6" >0.6</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="1.6" >1.6</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="2.6">2.6</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="3.6">3.6</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="4.6">4.6</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   <option value="6">6</option>
   <option value="7">7</option>
   <option value="8">8</option>
   <option value="9">9</option>
   <option value="10">10</option>
   <option value="11">11</option>
   <option value="12">12+</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-5">
  <select class="form-control" data-parsley-type="number" id="exp_max" name="exp_max">
   <option value="">Max</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="1.6">1.6</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="2.6">2.6</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="3.6">3.6</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="4.6">4.6</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   <option value="6">6</option>
   <option value="7">7</option>
   <option value="8">8</option>
   <option value="9">9</option>
   <option value="10">10</option>
   <option value="11">11</option>
   <option value="12">12+</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: What if i select the max value first and then the min value. What your code results to?

Comment: i get to see error in your code "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'autoHideNotify'

Answer (score 1):

You need to hide the options when you select a value for the `min` select dropdown. This code will be really helpful to you .

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#exp_min').change(function(){
    var selectedValue = parseFloat($(this).val());
    $('#exp_max option').each(function(){
       if(parseFloat($(this).val()) > selectedValue) {
          $(this).css('display', 'block' );
       }else{
          $(this).css('display', 'none' );
       }
    });
    $('#exp_max').val('');
    $('#exp_max').prop('disabled', false);
 })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" required data-parsley-minlength="1" id="exp_min"  name="exp_min">
   <option value="">Min</option>
   <option value="-1">Last Year Student</option>
   <option value="0">Fresher</option>
   <option value="0.6" >0.6</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="1.6" >1.6</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="2.6">2.6</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="3.6">3.6</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="4.6">4.6</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   <option value="6">6</option>
   <option value="7">7</option>
   <option value="8">8</option>
   <option value="9">9</option>
   <option value="10">10</option>
   <option value="11">11</option>
   <option value="12">12+</option>
  </select>

    <select class="form-control" data-parsley-type="number" id="exp_max"  name="exp_max" disabled>
   <option value="">Max</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="1.6">1.6</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="2.6">2.6</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="3.6">3.6</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="4.6">4.6</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   <option value="6">6</option>
   <option value="7">7</option>
   <option value="8">8</option>
   <option value="9">9</option>
   <option value="10">10</option>
   <option value="11">11</option>
   <option value="12">12+</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Thanks, @AKA this is also an alternative answer. Thank You.

Comment: Sure sir, your efforts are appreciable. Thank You.

Comment: @AKA - Why are you hungry for votes and points? SO is for sharing knowledge and not for asking votes and green ticks.

Comment: @MilanChheda is this anything concerned to you. I haven't asked you and if you do not believe on points then discard you 1,267  points and open a new account.